# Grep multiple lines in a directory

Tags: regular-expressions, rgrep

I have a regular expression that can match several lines of text, and I want to use it to search every file in a directory. The problem is that standard `regrep` command works line by line, so this multiline regular expression won't work.

Is there any alternative Lisp function/command that can do what I want?

Answer (score 5):

[Elgrep](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep) works with Emacs regular expressions. Newlines within the regular expression can be input by the key sequence <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>. The input of newlines works equally well when you use `elgrep-menu` (menu item `Tools -> Search Files (Elgrep)...`) or when you call `elgrep` directly (e.g., via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `elgrep` <kbd>RET</kbd>).

You can install [elgrep via Melpa](https://melpa.org/#/elgrep).

Answer (score 2):

n.b. The following isn't *really* useful beyond a simple list of matching filenames as the reported matching line will almost certainly be the first line -- so Emacs can't trivially take you to the matching text.

---

GNU `grep` supports the (non-POSIX) command line option `-z` (or `--null-data`), with the effect:

> Treat input and output data as sequences of lines, each terminated by a zero byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline

So you can (most likely) match against your entire file with that, with some caveats:

- *Output* is also NUL-terminated, so you need to parse that.
- NUL bytes are *already* used in the normal output (when `grep-use-null-filename-separator` is enabled), so you may need to differentiate those.
- You likely don't want to see the full text of the matching file in the output.

The following will probably do the trick for post-processing the NUL chars.

```
perl -pe 's/\0(?![0-9]+:)/\n/g'
```

And the `--only-matching` option will restrict the amount of displayed output.

Example using `M-x grep`:

```
grep --only-matching --null-data --color -nH --null -e REGEXP FILES | perl -pe 's/\0(?![0-9]+:)/\n/g'
```